# Using Vectors with functions, Pointer Issues

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have gotten myself completely muddled up and confused when it comes to these points and vectors.

I have two functions

```
 vector<int>& add(vector<int>& num1, vector<int>& num2){

     vector<int> ansVec;
     ....
     return ansVec;
 }
```

and

```
vector<int>& multiply(vector<int>& num1, vector<int>& num2){
    ...
    return add( multiply(num1, num2), multiply(num1, num2));
}
```

The issue seems to be that I'm returning a reference to a local variable.
How could I pass the entire vector, and not just the reference?

Comment: `vector<int> add...` But the real problem seems to be infinite recursion in your `multiply` function.

Comment: If the size is 1, then it returns a number higher up in the function.

Comment: Now it has the error: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::vector<int>&' from an rvalue of type 'std::vector<int>'

Comment: Most likely that is because `vector<int>& foo` cannot bind `vector<int>&&`. Depending on which part causes problem, you either want `vector<int> foo` or `vector<int> const& foo`. Really, you might want to post larger piece of your code, or the smallest reproducing example you can find.

Comment: have you looked at `std::valaray` instead of vector?

Answer (score 1):

you cannot always return by reference,
here are some solutions to your problem :

**1)** put the result in a container parameter:

```
void add(vector<int>& num1, vector<int>& num2 ,vector<int>* result)
```

and fill the result vector with the result of the computation

**2)** return by value :

```
vector<int> add(vector<int>& num1, vector<int>& num2);
```

note that here you actually copy each element from the temporary vector you will use for the computation, to the returned vector

**3)** return a pointer (or a some kind of smart pointer) to a vector allocated **on heap**

```
vector<int>* add(vector<int>& num1, vector<int>& num2)
{
vector<int>* res = new vector<int>();
...
return res ;
}
```

note that here the clients of this code must not forget to delete the vector

or , for example with *boost::shared_ptr* , or *std::shared_ptr* if you have c++11:

```
shared_ptr<vector<int>> add(vector<int>& num1, vector<int>& num2)
{

shared_ptr<vector<int>> res (new vector<int>());
...
return res ;
}
```

Comment: Use `unique_ptr`, not `shared_ptr`, when returning a newly created resource.  Conversion from unique to shared is easy, but the opposite is impossible.

Comment: your comments regarding 2) are false in 11.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be better off using std algorithms for carrying our addition/multiplication of vector e.g. use std::transform for adding two vectors or for multiplication

```
//Add vec1 and vec2 and store the results in result vec
//Note: take care of the ranges of two sources/destination
transform(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec2.begin(), result.begin(), std::plus<int>());
```

Issues with your code:

1. returning reference of the local variable
2. multiply doesn't have a terminating condition.

Comment: THanks for the idea! I agree it would be better, but I'm hoping to understand how to manually do it in preparation for an exam! THank you!

Comment: When it comes to c++, stick to references when creating interfaces/methods like you mentioned, pointers are for internal representation of your class.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, life is easier. Just return by value. It will automatically apply move semantics as opposed to copy semantics. Copying vectors is expensive, but moving them is cheap. Do not bother with pointers or references unless you are willing to profile your code and prove that it is a bottleneck. Using a pointer or reference here obfuscates code, and is a premature optimization.

See this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnqTKD8uD64. He takes up this exact issue, and recommends return by value for any type that is cheap to move.

Edit: when I say don't bother with references/pointers, I mean for returning. Passing in a const ref to a vector for input arguments, and a non-const ref to a vector for an in/out argument, is standard and good practice.